# Can a branch open multiple pull requests

Tags: github, pull-request

I am not too familiar with GitHub, but I have a feature branch that I want to merge its current changes to master multiple times. Ideally, I want to break up the pull requests so that one pr doesn't get too long. So for example I want a pr for the frontend first. After that is merged, I will push changes for the backend and create another pr. I wanted to make sure that the same feature branch can have multiple prs to master (but there will only be one open pr).

Is this allowed in Github?

Comment: Yes you can open multiple PRs for one branch. Just keep committing to the same branch after the PR has closed, and don't delete the branch.

Answer (score 0):

@aspiringsomeone, it is a good strategy to keep each PR incremental, self-contained and concise. However, it is good to create a new branch for new set of changes (features). In GIT, branches are just markers and don't consume too much space/resources. After your PR is merged, you can delete the branch and create a new branch for next PR.

In your case, first branch could be feature1_frontend (Hopefully, these changes don't depend on backend or somehow disabled until backend changes are ready). After PR_1 is merged, you can create feature1_backend branch and use it for next PR, say PR_2. As and when PR review is complete and it is merged, you can delete corresponding branches and move on.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, pull requests should be independent.

Do *not* keep a long-lived feature branch on hand and keep merging it (the same branch). That is a good way to end up with a zillion merge conflicts. You should always delete a PR branch as soon as it is merged.

But don't worry. If one pull request has to depend on another, there's a much better approach: In GitHub you can actually open multiple PRs that stem from one another, and that's probably the way to proceed here. So:

1. Branch off of your main branch to form `feature1` and push it and open a PR asking to merge to the main branch.
2. Branch off of `feature1` to form `feature2` and push it and open a PR asking to merge to `feature1`.
3. Branch off of `feature2` to form `feature3` and push it and open a PR asking to merge to `feature2`.

Here's the cool part. When `feature1` is approved and merged to the main branch, GitHub will automatically rebase the `feature2` PR so that it is now asking to merge to the main branch, which is just what you want. And so on.